# Android webview add header to each request without using shouldInterceptRequest

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview, android-websettings

I want to add my header to each request in webview but I dont want recreate the request using OkHttp or DefaultHttpClient since WebResourceRequest from shouldInterceptRequest does not return the request body so my POST requests wont have value when i send it.

I tried adding my header inside shouldInterceptRequest but i doesnt work properly seems its not adding on each request.

```
  override fun shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): WebResourceResponse? {
            request?.requestHeaders?.clear()
            request?.requestHeaders?.apply {
                put("header", "value") 
            }
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try passing the header values via the `view: WebView` param using:

```
public void loadUrl(@NonNull String url, @NonNull Map<String, String> additionalHttpHeaders) {
```

so something like:

```
  override fun shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): WebResourceResponse? {
    view.loadUrl("your url", mapOf("header" to "value"))
    return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)
  }
```

Comment: that is giving me this error.  'A WebView method was called on thread 'ThreadPoolForeg'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread.'